# Android: Why different AsyncTask's have different TID's?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have `Activity` generating 2 same `Class` `AsyncTask` by calling:

```
new SomeTask().execute();
new SomeTask().execute();
```

When debugging - Calling `android.os.Process.myTid()` from `doInBackground` I get different `TID` for each one of them. Which means that each `AsyncTask` is executing on different `Thread`.

BUT it seems in contradiction to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) saying:

> Starting with HONEYCOMB, task**s** are executed on a single thread...

What is the explanation here?

Target API: 23

Running on: 22

Min API: 15

Compiled: 23

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myTid()` returns the thread ID, not the process ID, as is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#myTid%28%29). The thread IDs of two parallel `AsyncTask` threads will be different.

**UPDATE**: In terms of why the two thread IDs differ, if you look at [the source code to `AsyncTask`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java), the `Executor` used with `execute()` is the `SerialExecutor` by default. That's not actually a single-thread thread pool, but rather is a serializing wrapper around the main multi-thread thread pool (`THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`) that we typically use with `executeOnExecutor()`. That thread pool is initialized with a few threads at the outset (# of cores + 1). My guess is that the `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` just hands subsequent jobs off round-robin to threads, which would result in separate thread IDs.

A better way to think of `execute()` is that only one `AsyncTask` will run at a time, not necessarily that all such `AsyncTask` instances will run on the same thread.

Comment: But the docs says unless you run on executor that you have 2 threads: 1 for the UI and 1 as "general worker" for all other AsyncTask's etc. `Process` not relevant here (it's 1 process per app and its the ui thread because it's linux based and thread=process)

Comment: @michael: Ah, now I see what your concern is. What version of Android are you running on? And what is your `targetSdkVersion`? "Process not relevant here" -- except you were the one who brought it up ("I get different PID"). Process IDs (PID) and thread IDs (TID) are different things, and your question seems to mix and match them.